# How to silence the commit function from the python apt library?

Tags: python, apt

I use python apt library and I would like that the `commit()` function doesn't produce any output.

I've searched on the web and saw that the fork function can do the trick but I don't know how to do that or if there exists another way. I don't use any GUI, I work via the terminal.

Comment: If it just contains prints, you can use: `saved=sys.stdout; sys.stdout=open("/dev/null", "w"); commit(); sys.stdout=saved`.  If the issue is that it launches subprocesses that you would like to silence, use `saved=os.dup(1); fd=os.open("/dev/null", os.O_WRONLY); os.dup2(fd, 1); os.close(fd); commit(); os.dup2(saved, 1); os.close(saved)`.  Unsure if that really answers your question, because it's unrelated to fork()...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is probably to use something like:

```
class LogInstallProgress(apt.progress.base.InstallProgress):
    def fork(self):
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid == 0:
            logfd = os.open("dpkg.log", os.O_RDWR | os.O_APPEND | os.O_CREAT, 0o644)
            os.dup2(logfd, 1)
            os.dup2(logfd, 2)
        return pid
```

and then in commit():

```
 cache.commit(install_progress=LogInstallProgress())
```

But be careful, note that deb packages may do conffile prompts and similar things, so you will want to override conffile() (and error too).

Answer (score 0):

The use to fork is just a possibility I think. I've already try to redirect the sys.stdout even the sys.stderr : No Joy, it won't work.